# How to secure the webservice URL from iphone?

Tags: ios, web-services, security, ios4

i have been working with iphone app calling webservices (php with parameters) many times. But how ever i was asking is it secure?  I heard of network monitoring tool which can detect out going data and thus get the url + parameters. but are there any other ways thats the url + parameters can de detected? Log console of the app?

Many thanks :)

Comment: Encode the content and use the POST method to pass the value to the server

Comment: encode the content .. you mean encoding by parameters + url by using utf 8 encoding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the web-service side implements security protocols like SSL and use HTTPS secure by defaults.That is ,encrypting your sensitive data by virtue of HTTPS. This is the same way eCommerce websites works on the online transactions.

Comment: Oki thanks for you immediate response.. but however if i use plain http and calling a url like www.example.com/?id=3&name=qwerty is there anyway to secure this? i mean if someone sees the parameters & url they will be able to call it from a web browser/ and or any http calling methods.

Comment: yeah yeah the same thing can be called from anywhere .To avoid this you may have to implement authentication using Oauth.A token based approach with user authorization and authentication